# How do I get the rendered content of a post created with Divi in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress site and the [Divi](https://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/) plugin used to create pages with the visual editor. I am developing a plugin that needs to get the content of some pages. I know that the page content created with Divi is stored on the database with shortcodes.

When I access the page content using wordpress functions I get the content full of shortcodes, but whenever you open the page built with Divi we can see the rendered HTML generated by these shortcodes. I want to be able to render the pages as rendered when you visit the site. I do not want to strip the shortcodes of the post.

Is there a wordpress function that renders the content as rendered when you open the page or is there a Divi function that already does it that I can use?

I already tried using both methods

```
$post = get_post(1);

//Method 1
echo do_shortcode( $post->post_content) ;

//Method 2
echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
```

but none of these rendered the Divi shortcodes to html.

Answer (score 6):

Try to use something like this

```
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
```

Comment: How do I use `get_the_content()` if I only have the post id?

Comment: @Sev load post by id and use `$my_post->post_content` instead of get_the_content()

Answer (score 2):

Full code:

```
// Render content of Divi page "404 page"
$args = array(
    'page_id' => 10302
);

$post_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $post_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $post_query->have_posts() ) {
        $post_query->the_post();
        $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
        echo $content;
    }
}

wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: this does not render block plugins properly as the needed css is missing, I want to know how to do it too